# Introduction to Statistical Learning Eq. 4.32

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, linear-algebra

Can someone please explain how the third line becomes the fourth line?
[image]

Comment: For vectors $u$ and $v$ and a *square symmetric* matrix $A$ you ask whether $y^\prime A y + u^\prime A u = (y-u)^\prime A (y-u) + 2u^\prime A y.$ This algebraic identify follows from the two properties listed at the left along with the symmetry of $A.$  Perhaps seeing the relation in this simpler notation will help you work through the steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an issue of expanding and tidying up.  You have for example

- $(x-\mu_k)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_k) = x^T\Sigma^{-1}x - \mu_k^T\Sigma^{-1}x-x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k+\mu_k^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k$ and
- $\mu_k^T\Sigma^{-1}x=x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k$ and $\mu_k^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_K=\mu_K^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k$ and
- $(\mu_k+\mu_K)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_k-\mu_K) = \mu_k^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k -\mu_K^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_K$

so

$\log\left(\frac{\pi_k}{\pi_K}\right) -\frac12(x-\mu_k)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_k) +\frac12(x-\mu_K)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_K)$
$= \log\left(\frac{\pi_k}{\pi_K}\right) -\frac12 x^T\Sigma^{-1}x+ x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k- \frac12\mu_k^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k +\frac12 x^T\Sigma^{-1}x- x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_K+ \frac12\mu_K^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_K$
$= \log\left(\frac{\pi_k}{\pi_K}\right) - \frac12(\mu_k^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k - \mu_K^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_K) + x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k- x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_K$
$= \log\left(\frac{\pi_k}{\pi_K}\right) - \frac12\mu_k^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k -\mu_K^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_K + x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_k- \mu_K)$

Answer (score 7):

Another way would be adding some terms to make the first multiplicands the same, and group (subtract the added terms outside of the parantheses as well):
$$\begin{align}A&=-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_k-\overbrace{\mu_K}^{new})^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_k)+\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_K-\overbrace{\mu_k}^{new})^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_K)\\&- \frac{1}{2}\mu_K^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_k)+\frac{1}{2}\mu_k^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_K)\rightarrow \text{subtract newly added terms}\\&=\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_k-\mu_K)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_k-\mu_K)+\frac{1}{2}x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_k-\mu_K)\\&=x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_k-\mu_K)-\frac{1}{2}(\mu_k+\mu_K)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_k-\mu_K)\end{align}$$

Note that $x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu=\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}x$ since inverse of cov. matrix is symmetric.

Comment: +1 for noting that symmetry is essential.